# React setState only if thing exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

So I am setting up a parent with several state attributes to pass to children. This is being done via AJAX. The trouble is that for some of these variables, the response may return `null` or `undefined`.

```
$.post(this.props.source, function(data) {

  // Parse the response
  var response = JSON.parse(data);

  if (this.isMounted()) {
    this.setState({

      // Set initial state vars
      minPrice:         response.resultDetails.minPrice,
      maxPrice:         response.resultDetails.maxPrice,
      language:         response.params.language,
      filters:          response.params.filters

    });
  }
}.bind(this));
```

How can I say something like `if response.params.language, set language`? I cannot figure out the React syntax to do such a thing.

Comment: `if (response.params.language) this.setState({language: response.params.language});` and so on for all 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should be doing this in `componentDidMount` so no need to check if `isMounted`
2. If you specify the `dataType` then jQuery will do a json parse for you and data will already be an object
3. If `response.params.language` is falsy (undefined), why would it matter if you set it - because you're overriding a non-falsy value?

You can do this in many vanilla JS ways.. this isn't related to React. e.g:

```
var newState = {
  minPrice: response.resultDetails.minPrice,
  maxPrice: response.resultDetails.maxPrice,
};

if (response.params.language) {
  newState.language = response.params.language;
}

if (response.params.filters) {
  newState.filters = response.params.language;
}

this.setState(newState);
```

or:

```
this.setState({
      minPrice: response.resultDetails.minPrice,
      maxPrice: response.resultDetails.maxPrice,
      language: response.params.language || this.state.language,
      filters: response.params.filters  || this.state.filters
});
```

Comment: I am doing `isMounted` inside `componentDidMount`, as per the React docs. Cheers though, ended up solving with ternary.

Comment: Np, I guess there's is a risk if your component is unmounted - might be worth having a look at this since isMounted is deprecated https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware. Weird that it still remains in the official docs. So you recommend just doing this just inside `componentDidMount`?

Comment: yep, if you're worried that the component might be unmounted before your request completes then you can set a var `this._isMounted = true` in `componentDidMount` and `this._isMounted = false` in `componentWillUnmount ` and use that to check as they suggest there